# Does simply pulling all users from firebase database and putting them into an array efficient?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple iOS app that part of the app grabs all the users from firebase database so you can search them, and do different functions. Now my question is, if/when the app grows and there are thousands of users, does pulling all the users from the database and adding them to an array of [user]'s, still not crash or slow the app? I see so many people on youtube just loop through firebase and grab all the users. Please note I am excluding profile photos so there is no downloading images involved, just strings. I have some code I thought could solve this possible problem, but I am starting to wonder if there even is a problem with just fetching all the users from firebase and putting them into and array and then displayed in a tableview.

Here is some of my code right now, but it still I notice when I type in one letter, then turn airplane mode on, it downloaded all the users. I really need some help or some advice on this one, thanks.

```
   var checklers = [String]()
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text == "" {
        filteredUsers = users
    }
    else {
       print("refreshing")
        if let uidi = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
            view.addSubview(activityInd)
            activityInd.startAnimating()
       filteredUsers.removeAll()
        checklers.removeAll()
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let userr = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                for (_, velt) in userr {
                    if let usernamerr = velt["Username"] as? String {
                    if usernamerr.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
                            let userNew = usera()
                            if let name = velt["Full Name"] as? String,  let uidd = velt["uid"] as? String {
                                userNew.name = name
                                userNew.username = usernamerr
                                userNew.uid = uidd
                                if self.checklers.contains(uidd) {
                                    print("already")
                                }
                                else {
                                    if userNew.uid != uidi {
                                self.filteredUsers.append(userNew)
                                        self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
                                        self.checklers.append(uidd)
                                    }

                                    print("added a user")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableViewSearchUser.reloadData()
                }
            }

        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()
        }
//            filteredUsers = users.filter( { ($0.username?.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()))! })
    }
    tableViewSearchUser.reloadData()
}
```

Please add any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for searching one or two users, each time a user would need to fetch all the records and putting them all in an array (all in memory). You want SQL-where query function, but Firebase is just different and doesn't have it.

**Problem with storing fetching all data approach:**

1) Storing just all the user's information in an array of user objects is NOT scalable on client's device.

2) When the number of users gets to ten of thousands, a day worth of search by a single user will eat up a sizable amount of real time database read quota.

3) Stale user data, an user has to re-download all the users just becauase on user changed his name to Doggie1 to doggieTwo.

**Solutions:**

1) If you haven't done so already, I suggest the options of doing some server-side filtering first by following the best practice here:

[Firebase Retrieving Data - Filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data)

Downloading a sub-set of user that fits some criteria and then do a bit of client-side filtering. Still is problematic when users get to tens of thousands.

Firebase has a client-size data persistence feature, but in your case if there filtering rule doesn't fit your need, you need do you own caching with some persistent storage solution. Instead of putting the fetched object in an Array[User], I would store each in a database SQLite on iOS and Android apps.

2) Implement a ElasticSearch with the FlashLight plugin, this involves some extra setup (I know, I've been through it, I learned quite a bit), but it is well worth it for autocomplete and search functions that Firebase currently doesn't support.

[A pluggable integration with ElasticSearch to provide advanced content searches in Firebase.](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight)